# Data storage design for nested data

Tags: java, sql, xml, database

So I am writing a fairly simple Java application for a school project, which basically has to store some information about various companies that will be inputted by the user.

The kind of data will be something like:

```
Company1
    Survey1
        Category 1
            Question 1
            ....
        Category 2
        ....
    Survey2
    ....
Company2
....
```

I originally thought of using a sqlite db for storing this, but I am not sure how to store nested data like this in a db without repeating data a lot. Then I thought of using XML or something.

So what would be a good way to store this data: sql database, xml or something else?

Comment: I would do whatever you think is simplest. A school project its unlikely to matter too much provided it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store as XML or store it in a db like this:

```
TABLE Companies
-------------------
CID (INT) | SID (INT REF)
-------------------

TABLE Surveys
-------------------
SID (INT) | SNAME (VARCHAR) | CATNAME (INT REF) | QUESTION (INT REF)
-------------------

TABLE Categories
-------------------
CID INT | CATNAME VARCHAR
-------------------

TABLE Question
-------------------
QID INT | QUESTION VARCHAR
-------------------
```

Comment: I think I might try something like this. I will create the database with: `create table if not exists companies (company TEXT, surveyID INTEGER, catRef INTEGER)`, 
`create table if not exists categories (catID INTEGER, catName TEXT)` and 
`create table if not exists questions (questionID INTEGER, question TEXT, catRef INTEGER)`

I think we are supposed to use a db, but as usual the instruction is vague and the teacher's answers are even more vague

Answer (score 2):

I think a SQL DB is isn't necessary.
I would do something like this:

```
Class Data {
   List<Company> companies;
}

Class Company {
   List<Survey> surveys;
}

Class Survery {
   List<Category> categories;
}

Class Category {
   List<Question> questions;
}

Class Question {
   String question;
}
```

Each company has its own surveys, which have their own categories, which have their own questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use XML to store data, Best way to do is create a class hierarchy that represent your data hierarchy (as @Doug Ramsey Posted). Create objects from your data and use JAXB(Java Architecture for XML Binding) to convert that objects in to XML file.